Instruments of Xcode not showing correct memory allocation on the latest version of iOS for PacketTunnelProvider Process
We have observed for a few months that the Instruments tool in Xcode does not show correct memory allocation for the PacketTunnelProvider process on iOS 17. The memory allocation does not exceed 6-7 MB, which is not the case with iOS 16 or 15. Additionally, Instruments crashes the PacketTunnelProvider process after profiling for a few minutes.
Please note that I am not running Xcode in debugger mode for the PacketTunnelProvider process along with instruments, as this is a known issue that causes the PacketTunnelProvider to be killed when both Instruments and the Xcode debugger are running.
Is anyone else facing this issue and have a workaround?
